# How can I easily open a command prompt in current folder with /u (set to unicode output)?

Tags: windows, command-line, unicode, dir

I'm trying to output directory and .txt file names using the following:

```
dir /b /s /a:d >> "filenames.txt"
dir /b /s *.txt >> "filenames.txt"
```

But some of the file and directory names use non-ASCII characters. If I put these in a .bat file, open cmd with `/u`, navigate to the folder I want and open the .bat file, it does what I want.

But I want to speed this process up, it has too many steps. Is there a way to make this less clumsy/winded?

Comment: What's wrong in `cmd /U /C dir /b /s /a:d >> "filenames.txt"` ?

Comment: Didn't know you can do that. That's perfect, thank you!